# Unit testing of class using File.OpenRead()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I would like to test a class that is using the method `File.OpenRead()` to obtain the content of a file. After reading the content of the file then it processes them. I have create an interface and a class that wraps the static `OpenRead()` method. But I encounter the problem that `OpenRead()` returns a `FileStream` and I have no idea how to "mock" the file stream.

Currently, I am creating a file just to create a `FileStream`... Of course, the tests are regularly failing with a `IOException` because the file is still in use...

Stripped Example:
Class:

```
class FileProcessor
{
  public FileProcessor(IFileWrap fileWrap) // fileWrap only redirects the calls to the static methods of File class
  { ... }

  public void Process(string file)
  {
    var content = fileWrap.ReadAllLines(file);

    // process content
  }
}
```

And the test:

```
[TestClass]
public class FileProcessor_Test
{
  [TestMethod]
  Process_FileNotReadable_Exception()
  {
    File.WriteAllText(testFile, "something");
    var fileWrapMock = new Mock<IFileWrap>();
    FileProcessor dut = new FileProcessor(fileWrapMock.Object);
    var actualException = AssertException.Throws<Exception>(() => dut.Process(testFile));
  }
}
```

I would like to avoid creating an abstraction of `FileStream`, too.

I was hoping that I could create a `MemoryStream` and somehow use this as the input, but this would require to change the file wrapper and deviate from the actual `File` class.

Any input is appreciated :)

Edit:
The processing includes computing a MD5 checksum by calling `ComputeHash()` from the the class `MD5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original method is tightly coupled to the fact that it operates on a file. Don't do that. Make the method take a [`Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx), *any* stream. You can operate on a [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx), or you can pass a [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) for testing.

```
public void Process(string file)
```

Should be

```
public void Process(Stream stream)
```

If you want to, you could have a second method overload for convenience:

```
public void Process(string file)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
    {
        this.Process(stream);
    }
}
```

*That* indeed cannot and should not be unit tested... it's .NET code handling external resources, at some point you have to trust the framework.

---

To address your edit: most Framework classes do something similar, for example the MD5 class has a [ComputeHash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa627k19(v=vs.110).aspx) method that works on a stream.

Comment: I was thinking about changing the class to operate on a `Stream` instead, but I thought this would only suspend the problem of creating the stream to a different place... Does I not need to check what happens if the stream creation fails, e.g. because of an file access error? And wouldn´t I then test the handling of these problem?

Comment: If you write an integration test (not a unit test) - you need to take care of this problem.

Comment: Are you sure, that an unit test should not check the handling of the stream creating exception? Even it only wraps the exception into a different one and adds some more information.

Comment: @royalTS Well you could if you wanted... you could write a unit test for a non-existant file for the method above. All I'm saying is that file handling is no longer a *unit* test because it operates on more than it's *unit*. And you need a way to write all those tests that don't fail without actually having to access the file system, that is what the stream argument gives you.

Comment: @nvoigt thanks! I will change the class to operate on streams and any superior using it, will be responsible for creating the stream.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need to unit test 'File' class as 'OpenRead' is a static method of 'File' class which you cannot decouple. It is not ideal to write a unit test against anything which has a dependency. In your case, you can mock 'IFileWrap' and create a mock method for 'ReadAllLines'. When unit test hits 'fileWrap.ReadAllLines(file)' method it will call the mock method instead of going to 'File.OpenRead()' method.

Comment: Actually, `IFileWrap` already contains a definition for the `ReadAllLines()` method. Indeed, I could use it to get the content of the file.

Comment: But your unit test shouldn't go the definition of 'ReadAllLines()' as there will be a dependency to 'File.OpenRead()' which will go and hit your actual file, which is not a unit test but an integration test. Unit test shouldn't have any dependency

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make IFileWrap return a string (read all lines) instead of MemoryStream. Basically, It is possible to create an abstraction over File, that will encapsulate File inside it.

Comment: `IFileWrap` returns a `FileStream` just like `File.OpenRead()`. I was hoping to create a `MemoryStream` somewhere in my test and provide this as a `FileStream`.

Comment: If you need the content of the file, you can create an interface that returns this content (string or byte[]), and inside implementation play with streams. It can significantly simplify your tests.